# C++ / variadic template & parameter pack using decltype(lambda)

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, variadic-templates, decltype

I am sorry to ask a question that was may be asked before, but I searched long enough and did not find an answer.

My problem is that I would like to call a template function of type `template <typename GenericLambda, typename... LambdaArgs>` without the need to always write `decltype(my_lambda)` first in the template parameters.

```cpp
    #include <functional>
    #include <string>

    template <typename GenericLambda, typename... LambdaArgs>
    auto lambda_to_mem_fn() {
        auto ptr = &GenericLambda::template operator() < LambdaArgs... > ;
        auto as_mem_fn = std::mem_fn(ptr);
        return as_mem_fn;
    }

    auto my_lambda = [](auto x, auto y) { return x + y; };


    // imaginary function
    template <????>
    auto make_lambda_to_mem_fn(GenericLambda generic_lambda) 
    {
        // Extract lambda args types and forward them to lambda_to_mem_fn
        using GenericLambda = decltype(generic_lambda);
        lambda_to_mem_fn<GenericLambda, LambdaArgs...>();
    }


    void test() {
        // How to remove the need to write decltype(my_lambda) ?
        auto as_mem_fn = lambda_to_mem_fn<decltype(my_lambda), int, int>;

        // I would like to write:
        auto as_mem_fn2 = make_lambda_to_mem_fn<int, int>(my_lambda);
    }
```

I need a solution that is portable (i.e works on gcc, clang and msvc).

I'm scratching my head since quite some time in this, and would appreciate some help ;-)

Link to compiler explorer snippet:
https://godbolt.org/z/pFk09J

Comment: "without the need to always write decltype(my_lambda)" - why is this an issue?

Comment: Because I'm writing a library, and I would like to make its API as easy to use as possible

Comment: Put `typename GenericLambda` *after* `typename... LambdaArgs`, i.e., `<???>=<typename... LambdaArgs, typename GenericLambda>`

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki : ouch, I am tired! Thanks a lot. I did not even dare to put the pack first, although it was the solution.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki : I you are interested in reps points, please post an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The restriction where a parameter pack (if present) must be the final parameter in a template parameter list applies only to primary class templates. If the type can be deduced or defaulted, it can appear after the parameter pack:

```
template <typename... LambdaArgs, typename GenericLambda>
auto make_lambda_to_mem_fn(GenericLambda generic_lambda) 
{
    return lambda_to_mem_fn<GenericLambda, LambdaArgs...>();
}
```

Any template arguments will be consumed by `LambdaArgs`, while `GenericLambda` will be deduced from the argument expression.